# When forming an n channel in an N mosfet, do the pn junctions of the drain-substrate and source-substrate parts disappear?

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

When forming an n channel in an N mosfet, do the pn junctions of the drain-substrate and source-substrate parts disappear?

Here's what I expected:

1. When gate voltage (higher than threshold voltage) applied, free electrons will be attracted into substrate-oxide interface.
2. The source-substrate and drain-substrate portions of the oxide-substrate interface would move these free electrons toward the source and drain.
3. As a result, there is an N channel between the drain and source, but even if $v_{DS}<v_{OV} (v_{GD}>v_{TH})$, it does not completely connect the source and drain: a depletion layer exists at the edge of the channel.

I know that this result is wrong. If $v_{DS}<v_{OV} (v_{GD}>v_{TH})$, n channel completely connect source and drain.

So, which of the processes I was thinking about was wrong and how?